# How to replace the commas in the json result using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Json result : `Hi,xxx,yy,,,welcome`

I have tried as the following:

```
var bfrreplace = ' Hi,xxx,yy,,,welcome';     
    bfrreplace.replace(/,/g, ' ');
```

Which results as `Hi xx yy welcome` but I need the results as : `Hi xxx yy ,welcome`

With Thanks.

Comment: First thing is `Hi,xxx,yy,,,welcome` is not a json but seems a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  i can see it is a string not a json structure which requires to be a pair of keys and values like `{key:value}`.

In your issue you can use `.match()` with `foreach` loop call to create your required string `Hi xxx yy ,welcome`:

```js
var bfrreplace = ' Hi,xxx,yy,,,welcome', // the string
    arr = bfrreplace.match(/([a-z0-9A-Z])+/g), // .match(regex) to create an array
    newStr='';  // new string to create as per requirement.

[].forEach.call(arr, function(s, i) { // loop over the created array
   newStr += (i == arr.length - 1) ? " ," + s : " " + s; // adds a comma to the last value
});

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = newStr; // finally use the new String.
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

But if you need a comma separated value then just use `.match(regex).join(', ')` :

```js
var bfrreplace = ' Hi,xxx,yy,,,welcome', // the string
    str = bfrreplace.match(/([a-z0-9A-Z])+/g).join(','); // .match(regex) to create an array

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = str; // finally use the new String.
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks..Its Working :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple `split()` and `join()` to split the string based on deliminator i.e. `,` then filter out empty strings and join the array elements to form the string.

```js
var bfrreplace = ' Hi,xxx,yy,,,welcome';
bfrreplace = bfrreplace
  .split(',') //Will create an array
  .filter(function(n) {
    return n != undefined && n.length > 0; //Filter out empty elements
  })
  .join(','); //Return joined string
snippet.log(bfrreplace)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```